# What happens to a quasi-undead creature when fortunate fate activates?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, undead, healing

The creature casts the 8th-level spell *veil of undeath* [necro] (*SpC* 229), which says, in part, that

> Like an undead creature, you are damaged by *cure* spells and healed by *inflict* spells.  You don’t actually gain the undead type from casting this spell.

Then the creature is the target of the 7th-level Clr spell *fortunate fate* [conj] (*SpC* 99), which says, in part, that

> You surround the subject with an aura that immediately heals the creature if it is subjected to an effect that would kill it (reduce its hit points to -10 or below). When this event occurs, the *fortunate fate* spell intervenes by immediately triggering a *heal* spell upon the target.

If the creature's reduced to -10 hp or below before the expiration of the spells *fortunate fate* and *veil of undeath*, what happens?

1. The creature is the subject of the spell *fortunate fate*'s *heal* effect and regains hp; the spell *heal* is neither a *cure* spell nor an *inflict* spell, and the creature looks like a genius.
2. The creature's *even deader* upon the spell *fortunate fate*'s activation; the spell *veil of undeath* uses *cure* and *inflict* spells as shorthand for positive and negative energy, and the creature looks like an idiot.
3. Your answer, if neither of the above.

Comment: Use the Magic of Faerûn version of fortunate fate which states: If this spell is cast upon an undead creature, it uses a harm spell instead of heal.

Comment: @briddums That's... interesting. However, in this case, the target of the spell *fortunate fate* isn't technically undead.

Answer (score 9):

Rules-as-written, you’re only healed by *inflict* and damaged by *cure*, not otherwise treated like an undead creature for, e.g., *heal* and *harm*.

Which is ridiculous, but they worded *veil of undeath* very poorly.

I would never play it that way, and I’d have *heal* damage a creature under the effects of *veil of undeath*.

On the other hand, I’d probably also allow a player to cast a version of *fortunate fate* that casts *harm* instead of *heal*. Actually, I’d most likely just let *fortunate fate* be smart enough to cast the correct version when it was triggered.

Answer (score 2):

I think the intention behind the *veil of undeath* spell was that the caster would be harmed by all healing spells(positive energy) and healed by all harm spells(negative energy). As KRyan pointed out, the spell wasnt worded very well so that would have to be made as an assumption, which isnt always the "right" answer. I believe the mention of not getting the undead creature type is to avoid also getting immunities to crit, and Damage Reduction, etc. Other things that "Undead" creature all get.

That being said, They way I would rule it, is as I stated above, because that makes the most sense to me. So heal would also hurt the creature with *veil of undeath* and harm would act as heal.

Second to that, I would also take KRyan's stance of letting the spell caster or the spell itself, choose which way to go, as its a fairly powerful spell(7th level) and has a particular affect in mind.